# Which days in Sept-Oct ought I book, to see fall foliage in Charlevoix?

Tags: quebec

Flights ought be bought now for lower prices, but how to forecast the best days? The quotes beneath contradict: the 1st 2 recommend mid to late September, but the last one the 1st week of Oct.

[National Post dated Sep 8 2015](https://nationalpost.com/travel/dont-miss-quebecs-fall-colours-september-is-best-for-viewing-an-explosion-of-colour-in-the-countryside):

> [Tourism Quebec](https://www.quebecoriginal.com/en)’s Claudette Lacombe says bursts of red, yellow and orange will soon begin to appear as leaves change colours with the approach of fall.
>
> “The peak is from the end of September up to mid-October, but if visitors don’t want to miss the colours they should come in mid-September until the end of September,” she said in a recent interview.
>
> [...] Anyone planning a fall colour tour in the province should check the bilingual website Quebecoriginal.com starting in mid-September. **[I'm aware of this website.]**

[User 'rickb' from Tripadvisor. Feb 6 2013](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g155025-i50-k6109462-o10-Where_in_Charlevoix_area_as_a_base_for_fall_foliage-Quebec.html):

> Back to the fall colors. October is too late for peak season in Charlevoix, hence my suggestion of moving to the Mont-Tremblant area where it will be in full bloom.

[User 'Jean-Simon C' from Tripadvisor. Feb 3 2013](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g155025-i50-k6109462-Where_in_Charlevoix_area_as_a_base_for_fall_foliage-Quebec.html):

> Perfect timing, the color peak is around the end of september/beginning october in this region.

Answer (score 5):

It varies from year to year and depends on the species too.

In some years it peaks mid-to-late September.

In other years it peaks in October.

Unless you live close enough to be flexible and travel on short notice, or you have enough time to travel for a long time, you'll have to gamble a bit.

It also depends on the species.  I've spent Canadian Thanksgiving (2nd week of October) in the Algonquin Provincial Park, and although most trees were already barren, the yellow larches gave a very strong far-north feel within a weekend's driving distance from the Toronto area.